# WSP package deployed through Powershell commands not reflecting the changes

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, solution-package, visual-studio-2012

There are few custom items like lists,content Types and pages which gets deployed through couple of features. When I directly deploy from visual studio, the custom items are deleted and recreated again as all the steps like retracting,removing,adding, deploying and feature activation happens within.

But when I am trying to deploy the WSP package through power shell command, these custom items are not getting updated.
Until I deactivate the features, delete all these and then activate the feature, its gets updated.

Please suggest me if I am missing anything here.

Thank You